# Share Android Play Store app link with my app

Tags: java, android, hyperlink

I would like to know how to add my app to the list of apps that appears when you click on the "Share" button while viewing an app in the Android Play Store. Right now there's a lot of apps that exist in that menu (from Mail to SMS, Facebook and a lot more) and selecting one of those "pastes" the message: "Check out  - ".

I would like to catch this link and use it inside my app.

I understand I should use a receiver that somehow catches the link from the Play Store app and some sort of filter but from the explanation on developer.android.com I don't really understand how to do that.

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your AndroidManifest.xml like this (creating an Intent filter for your acitivity for receiving shared text):

```
<activity android:name="com.yourpackage.YourActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In YourActivity all you have to do to get the Link you want is this:

```
String marketlink = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

Comment: Looks easy. But when I do this, won't my app be in the "Send" menu everywhere plain text is shared? I tried changing the `<data android:mimeType...>` to this `<data android:mimeType="text/plain" android:scheme="https" android:host="play.google.com" android:path="store/apps/"/>` or variations thereof but it doesn't work...my app disappears from the Send menu completely. Can I add some filter to make it only work with the Play Store?

Comment: Maybe add sth like `<action android:name="com.android.vending.XXXX"/>` ? no idea what the XXXX should be :(

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to do this. That's because the market fires an Intent with "text/plain" which is very general. You can not set your intent filter based on the content of a plain text.

Comment: I guess it should be ok like this. Thank you!